# Error al correr un Foreach ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Hola compañeros de Stack, actualmente quiero recorrer unos datos mediante un ciclo `foreach` pero tengo un problema siempre me arroja el siguiente error

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}"
>   character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the
>   "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters
>   are being interpreted as markup.

parte de mi controlador:

```
// GET: CalificarColaboradors
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            var calificado = (from p in db.CalificarColaboradors
                              where p.codigo_colaborador == id
                              select p.codigo_objetivos).ToList();

            var codigo = calificado[0];

            ViewBag.listobjetivos = (from p in db.Objectives
                                     where p.Codigo_Objetivos == codigo
                                     select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.calificacion = (from p in db.CalificarColaboradors
                                    where p.codigo_objetivos == codigo
                                    select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.fecha_actual = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ViewBag.Data_Collaborator = (from p in db.Collaborators
                                         where p.codigo == id
                                         select p).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

Parte de mi vista:

```
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: rgba(112, 183, 50, 0.35);">
    <th>Objetivos</th>
    <th>Peso: 20%</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Calificación</th>
    <th>Observación</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var i in ViewBag.listobjetivos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@i.Nombre_Objetivo</td>
            <td>@i.Peso_Objetivo%</td>
            <td>@i.Descripcion_Objetivo</td>
    }

@foreach (var o in ViewBag.calificacion)
    {
            <td>@o.calificacion</td>
            <td>@o.observacion</td>
        </tr>
    }


</tbody>
```

y una imagen del como se ve por el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error se soluciona cuando en el primer `foreach` `@foreach (var i in ViewBag.listobjetivos)` se cierra el  pero no es la idea, porque necesito que ambos foreach sean una linea.

Cualquier duda o cuestion quedo atento.

> UPDATE

Me dicen que puedo hacer un join en la consulta para anidarlas o juntarlas, pero sinceramente no se como se realiza el procedimiento mis tablas son estas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente hacerlo de la siguiente forma y me salen 16 resultados, y en este momento serian 4.

```
ViewBag.test = (from p in db.Objectives
                     join pm in db.CalificarColaboradors on p.Codigo_Objetivos
                     equals pm.codigo_objetivos
                         where pm.codigo_objetivos == codigo
                     select new { Post = p, Meta = pm }).ToList();
```

Comment: Asi no va a funccionar. en el primer foreach abres unn fila(tr) sin cerrarlo y en el segundo cierras sin abrir

Comment: Deberías realizar un join de tus consultas Linq y devolver una lista de una clase con las calificaciones y objetivos siempre y cuando esas entidades estén relacionadas. Es decir, un objetivo tiene unicamente una calificación? Puedes mostrar el diagrama de clases de ambas entidades?

Comment: Hola @SergioParraGuerra como podria hacer ese join?

Comment: pon tu esquema de las tablas CalificarColaboradors y Objetives, si tienen alguna relación es fácil que puedas hacer un inner join entre las 2 tablas y con una consulta sacar ls datos que necesitas.

Comment: no tienen relacion

Comment: Pero si los elementos de listobjetivos y de calificacion no tienen relación ¿cómo vas a mostrarlos en la misma fila? ¿cómo sabes que calificación corresponde a cada objetivo para mostrarlos juntos?

Comment: en la tabla calificarColaboradors tengo una columna llamada Codigo_Colaborador y tambien el ID_Objetivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El punto es que no requieres tener dos objetos en el `ViewBag`, realmente lo puedes lograr mediante un solo objeto haciendo un `join` a las tablas que desees consultar. Otra cosa es que como vamos a crear un objeto a partir de una consulta de dos tablas, en la vista no se puede acceder a un tipo anónimo, por lo que crearemos un modelo llamado `ObjetivesCollabotaros` el cual servirá de interacción entre el Controller y el View:

```
public class ObjetivesCollabotaros
{
    public string Nombre_Objetivo { get; set; }
    public decimal Peso_Objetivo { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion_Objetivo { get; set; }
    public decimal calificacion { get; set; }
    public string observacion { get; set; }
}
```

Los tipos de dato supongo que son esos, si llegaran a ser otros, solo debes ajustarlos a los correspondientes.

Aunque las tablas no tengan una relación implícita en la base de datos, se pueden relacionar mediante el campo `Objectives.id` y el `CalificarColaboradors .id_objetivo`. Viendo tu estructura de tablas, la consulta debería quedar algo así:

```
ViewBag.listobjetivos = (from p in db.Objectives
                        join o in db.CalificarColaboradors on p.id equals o.id_objetivo
                        where p.Codigo_Objetivos == codigo
                        && o.codigo_colaborador == id
                        select new ObjetivesCollabotaros {
                            Nombre_Objetivo = p.Nombre_Objetivo,
                            Peso_Objetivo = p.Peso_Objetivo,
                            Descripcion_Objetivo = p.Descripcion_Objetivo,
                            calificacion = o.calificacion,
                            observacion = o.observacion
                        }).ToList();
```

En la parte de la vista, solo se requiere iterar `ViewBag.listobjetivos` una sola vez:

```
@foreach (var i in ViewBag.listobjetivos)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@i.Nombre_Objetivo</td>
        <td>@i.Peso_Objetivo%</td>
        <td>@i.Descripcion_Objetivo</td>
        <td>@i.calificacion</td>
        <td>@i.observacion</td>
    </tr>
}
```